# Building Boost 1.56 with Intel C++ Compiler 2015 Windows

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, windows-8.1, icc

I have seen the other questions regarding compiling Boost with the Intel C++ compiler, however, I have had no luck.

I first launch the Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015 Composer Edition IA-32 Visual Studio 2013 CMD and then cd to my boost directory (C:\boost_1_56_0). I run bootstrap.bat (no problems here). I then run `b2 toolset=intel` and I get an error saying cannot find Intel compiler...

> C:/boost_1_56_0/tools/build/src/tools\intel-win.jam:57: in intel-win.init from module intel-win
>   error: No intel compiler version found!
>   C:/boost_1_56_0/tools/build/src/build\toolset.jam:43: in toolset.using from module toolset
>   C:/boost_1_56_0/tools/build/src/tools\intel.jam:32: in intel.init from module intel
>   C:/boost_1_56_0/tools/build/src/build\toolset.jam:43: in toolset.using from module toolset
>   C:/boost_1_56_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:461: in process-explicit-toolset-requests from module build-system
>   C:/boost_1_56_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:527: in load from module build-system
>   C:\boost_1_56_0\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:289: in import from module modules
>   C:\boost_1_56_0\tools\build\src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build from module
>   C:\boost_1_56_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module`

Is there some setting that I need to change so that it detects the Intel C++ 2015 compiler? The target is IA32 and I am using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: I'm surprised to see so many Boost 1.56 building questions recently, I hadn't realized the Boost libraries were still heavily in use

Comment: Experiencing the same problem here. @mmk have you found a solution?

Comment: @DevarshDesai let me assure you, there is absolutely no reason not to use Boost libraries

Comment: haha, @DmitriNesteruk, are there any modern comparables to the boost library. I've met people who try to achieve boost's async functionality in a C++-style language through using the Go language; have you heard of any modern C++ library that's better or popular these days? :0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've solved this one. Basically, when calling `b2`, `toolset=intel` no longer seems to do. I suspect that the bjam people have messed things up internally. To cut the story short, you now need to explicitly specify your toolset versions, so for example calling something like:

```
b2 toolset="intel-12.1-vc2013"
```

Yes, that's `vc` and not `vs`. Hope this helps.

**Update**: turns out that it doesn't work with Intel C++ 2015 but luckily you can simply change the `intel-win.jam` build file to [this content](http://pastebin.com/UZU5DM1a) to support the new 15.0 toolset and then run the build as `b2 toolset="intel-15.0"`. I've just rebuilt Boost this way, so I know it works.

Here's the command line I build it with: `b2 toolset="intel-15.0" address-model=64 threading=multi variant=release link=static -j 4`

Comment: Do you know exactly what to change? I am not very familiar with the build scripts used by Boost...

Comment: @mmk yeah, sorry, the file you need to change is `intel-win.jam` and here is what it needs to be: http://pastebin.com/UZU5DM1a